# maximum page size in itextpdf

Tags: itext

I'm creating adf project and generating reports using itextpdf 5.1.3.
For eg:- My table customer has 3000 rows.In my jspx page has customer table & button has file downloader listner there i'm simply calling the report.
Report is generating for only first 50 rows (maximum 4 pages) are only coming.
Why the remaining rows are not coming in reports?

```
private void generatePDFFile(FacesContext facesContext, java.io.OutputStream outputStream) {
    try {
        DCBindingContainer dcBindings = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
        DCIteratorBinding iterBind1 = (DCIteratorBinding)dcBindings.get("CustomerView1Iterator");

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE)); \\file path local disk D:\mywork\customer.pdf         
      document.open();
        Row[] rows= iterBind1.getAllRowsInRange();
        for(Row row:rows){   
        custcode = (String) row.getAttribute("CustomerCode");
        custname = (String) row.getAttribute("CustomerNameE");
        addgroup(document);
        }
        document.close();
        facesContext = facesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ServletContext context = (ServletContext)facesContext.getExternalContext().getContext(); 
        File file = new File(FILE); 
        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        byte[] b; 
        System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file); 
        int n = fileInputStream.available();
        while (n > 0) {
            b = new byte[n];
            //b = new byte[8192];
            int result = fileInputStream.read(b);
            outputStream.write(b, 0, b.length);
            if (result == -1)
                break;
        }
        outputStream.flush(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static void addgroup(Document document) throws DocumentException{

    Paragraph preface1 = new Paragraph();
    Paragraph preface2 = new Paragraph();
    preface1.add(new Chunk("\n"));
    preface1.add(new Chunk("Customer  : "+custcode+"      "+custname,BlueFont));
    preface1.add(new Chunk("\n"));
    document.add(preface1);
    document.add(preface2);

}
```

Comment: What a bad question. Could you improve it?

Comment: Hi Bruno,
My table has 3000 rows. when calling pdf generation only first 50 rows only coming.Why?
Below is my code....

Comment: Your code is not below. Thousands of developers have created PDFs using iText that have more than 3000 rows. If you'd ask me *why* your application only renders 50 rows, the answer is simple: because you are doing something wrong. What are you doing wrong? Maybe you shouldn't be using a version of iText that is almost 6 years old. Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: i'm new at this itext.
Just today only i started learning this itext .May be my coding is below par.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I just added my code.

Comment: This is not an iText problem. The problem is that `getAllRowsInRange()` only returns 50 rows.

Comment: Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size of a page in a PDF document is 14,400 by 14,400 user units. See the blog post [Help, I only see blank pages in my PDF](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/blankpage14400). This is not a limitation introduced by iText; it's a limitation that exists in PDF viewers such as Adobe Reader. Other viewers (such as Apple Preview) have no problem displaying PDFs with larger pages.

This answers the question in the Subject-line of your post.

The body of your post contains a completely different question. Maybe you aren't asking about the page size, but rather about the file size. That question has also been answered in the past. See [What is the size limit of pdf file?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/what-size-limit-pdf-file)

Allow me to summarize that answer:

- The maximum size of a PDF with a version older than PDF 1.5 is about 10 gigabytes.
- The maximum size of a PDF with a version PDF 1.5 or higher using a compressed cross-reference stream depends only on the limitations of the software processing the PDF.
- The maximum size of a PDF created with iText versions before 5.3 is 2 gigabytes. The maximum size of a PDF created with iText versions 5.3 and higher is 1 terabyte.

Since you are using iText 5.1.3, you can create a PDF of 2 GBytes. It beats me why you are using a version of iText that dates from November 2011 instead of a more recent version, but there is no reason why you wouldn't be able to put a table containing 3000 rows in a PDF that can be as large as 2 GBytes.

Chances are that your code is really bad. Unfortunately, you don't show us your code. Did you read the documentation on how to create [Large Tables](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables-itext5/large-tables)?

I can't comment on the part where you say:

> In my jspx page has customer table & button has file downloader listner there i'm simply calling the report.

That doesn't seem to be relevant in the context of your question.